# С# Exception Cannot load a reference assembly for execution

Tags: c#, исключения

В приложении `C# WinForms` возникает ошибка `Cannot load a reference assembly for execution`. В информации по ошибке есть номер строки. В этой строке просто вызывается функция foo. Выглядит примерно так

```
try
{
   foo(param1, param2);                    
}
catch (Exception ee)
{
   logError(ee);
}
```

ee.StackTrace выглядит так

```
Temp
at Temp.Program.parseProduct(HtmlDocument htmlPl, HtmlDocument htmlRu, String func, Int32 sort_order, String categoryId, Double koef, String url)
at Temp.Program.processProductsPage(String Url, String categoryId, String status) in ... :line 1886
```

Причем возникает такая ошибка вообще на другой машине, на моем компьютере ее не наблюдаю. Поэтому не могу продебажить в msvs. И что интересно, возникает вроде бы через раз. Т.е. этот код в цикле, и иногда функция срабатывает, а иногда выдает исключение.  Вопрос - что это за исключение и в каких случаях оно может возникать?

Comment: В тексте ошибки уже всё указано. Логируйте stack trace и смотрите, какая сборка и откуда не была загружена.

Comment: StackTrace — это хорошо. А какой тип исключения? Что в InnerException и FusionLog?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, у вас одна из используемых сборок зарегистрирована в GAC, поэтому у пользователя не работает функция. Или версия сборки пользователя устарела по отношению к вашей.

Comment: т.е. решение - скопировать локально все сборки, используемые в приложении?

Comment: Нужно указать, в свойствах сборки "Copy Local" -> "true", тогда при следующем Build сборки сами буду копироваться локально.